# How to separate out elements in a string using jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have made an Ajax call to an external site to grab some information from a specific element and return it on my site as a string.

This is the code for the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://cors.io/?u=http://www.spotlight.com/6298-9058-7917',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(res) {
      var data = $.parseHTML(res);           

       $(data).find('.credit').each(function(){
          $('#credits').append($(this).html());
     });

   }
 });
```

This get's all the contents of a div called `.credit` on the external site and returns it looking like this:

```
<div id="credits">
    <span class="creditYear">2010</span>, <span class="creditProductionType">Television</span>, <span class="creditCharacterRole">Cop Nicola Lanza</span>, <span class="creditProductionName">“Un posto al sole”</span>, <span class="creditCompany">Grundy</span>, <span class="creditDirector">Various</span><span class="creditYear">2008</span>, <span class="creditProductionType">Television</span>, <span class="creditCharacterRole">Lawyer Moroni</span>, <span class="creditProductionName">“Il Bene e il Male”</span>, <span class="creditCompany">Italy</span>, <span class="creditDirector">Giorgio Serafini</span>
</div>
```

Obviously, on my page this looks like a bit of a mess, what I'd like to be able to do is style it out nicely into a table. So for each set of results (i.e. year, production, character role, production name, company, director) there should be a row in a table, like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="year"></td>
        <td class="production_type"></td>
        <td class="character_role"></td>
        <td class="production_name"></td>
        <td class="company"></td>
        <td class="director"></td>
        <td class="director"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...but one row for each set of results. Would it be possible to append each corresponding credit (from the AJAX call) and display it in my table?

Comment: Receiving it like `,` separated `html`??

Comment: Shouldn't that output html have everything in a single `<tr>`, and then repeat every time `year` repeats?

Comment: @4castle yes you're right, just changed that in my question

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes that is exactly how it's coming back to me as comma separated html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by copying the data in each of the spans to the relevant cells of a table:

In your success callback:

```
// Set up the table however you want it to be formatted
var $tableTemplate = $('<table><tr>' +
  '<td class="year"></td>' +
  '<td class="production_type"></td>' +
  '<td class="character_role"></td>' +
  '<td class="production_name"></td>' +
  '<td class="company"></td>' +
  '<td class="director"></td>' +
  '</tr></table>');

$(data).find('.credit').each(function(){
  // Copy the data from the request to a copy of the table
  var $newTable = $tableTemplate.clone();
  var $creditData = $(this);
  $newTable.find('.year').text($creditData.find('.creditYear').text());
  $newTable.find('.production_type').text($creditData.find('.creditProductionType').text());
  $newTable.find('.character_role').text($creditData.find('.creditCharacterRole').text());
  $newTable.find('.production_name').text($creditData.find('.creditProductionName').text());
  $newTable.find('.company').text($creditData.find('.creditCompany').text());
  $newTable.find('.director').text($creditData.find('.creditDirector').text());

  // And append it to your div (or whatever you want to put it in)
  $('#credits').append($newTable);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/p5zetyam/

Comment: what is the $siteData variable in this?

Comment: @SamSkirrow accidentally left that in from the jsfiddle demo, I've changed it now

Comment: @SamSkirrow who knows? :P

Comment: @SamSkirrow FYI, I just realized for performance reasons I shouldn't really be re-wrapping `this` in jQuery object each time, so I changed the code a bit to store `$(this)` in a variable and use that instead.